# Why does the repository in an application event handler provide values that have not been updated?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot application with the JpaRepository.
There are actions in the application that are triggered by a scheduler.
After changing and saving an entity, an event is triggered to notify the rest of the system.
I now have the problem that the value was not updated when the event handler retrieves the entity from the repo.

Below is a highly simplified code section that hopefully clarifies the problem.

*A scheduler triggers an action every given time:*

```
@Component
public class MyScheduler {
    //...
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
    public void scheduleSomething() {
        entityService.doSomething();
    }
    //...
```

*A service modifies and stores an entity and then triggers an event to notify the system:*

```
    //...
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //...
        var entityId = // some other code
        var entity = entityRepo.findById(entityId);
        entity.setName("new name");
        eventMulticaster.multicastEvent(new MyEvent<>(this, entityRepo.save(entity)));
        // If the entity is retrieved from the repo again, the name has been correctly changed!
        //...
    //...
```

*When the event handler queries the entity, the value is not updated:*

```
    //...
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        //...
        var entityFormEvent = ((MyEntity) event.getPayload());
        print(entityFromEvent.getName()); // Prints the updated value.

        var entityFromRepo = entityRepo.findById(entityFromEvent);
        print(entityFromRepo.getName()); // Prints the value before the change!
        //...
```

It would be great if someone could help me and explain what I am doing wrong.
**Thank you very much!**

Answer (score -1):

Spring Event Listeners are synchronous unless you explicitly use `@Async` annotation and make it asynchronous. This means when the below line is called the transaction of `doSomething` is not yet committed.

```
eventMulticaster.multicastEvent(new MyEvent<>(this, entityRepo.save(entity)));
```

Thus you will not see the changes in `onApplicationEvent` method when you retrieve from `entityRepo`.

You can try using `JpaRepository.saveAndFlush` which will save and flush the changes immediately to Database and it should work.

```
eventMulticaster.multicastEvent(new MyEvent<>(this, entityRepo.saveAndFlush(entity)));
```

**UPDATE**

The other thing you can try is removing the `@Transactional` annotation from your `onApplicationEvent` method which will force the transaction created from `doSomething` method to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  
I had already tried `saveAndFlush`, unfortunately without success.  
Async should not change anything here according to my understanding.  
In my opinion, the transaction should be carried out with `entityRepo.save` (or `saveAndFlush`).  
The return value of this is then used for the event.  
If I place the save before the event and then retrieve the entity directly from the repo, the value is correct.  
Nevertheless, I have tried your suggestion, unfortunately without success.

Comment: Thank you again!
I have simplified entity for the explanation, in the real model there are several relationships to other models.
Since the action triggered by the scheduler is without session but should use the relationships, `@Transactional` is required as far as I know.
I have tested your suggestion, but immediately run into a `LazyInitializationException`.

Comment: @shazin With the synchronous event handler removing the @Transactional annotation from `onApplicationEvent()` won't change anything, because the default transaction propagation mode is `REQUIRED` - "Spring checks if there is an active transaction, and if nothing exists, it creates a new one. Otherwise, the business logic appends to the currently active transaction"